# Managing cached windows 10 domain credentials for remote users

Tags: active-directory, vpn, domain, windows-10

I support a network with several remote locations where the users can only connect in via VPN (Windows 10 built-in SSTP). Is there any way to manage / update what domain user credentials are cached on these machines, without having to haul them into the office? Assume I have access to local and domain admin credentials on the remote computers, but need to add a new remote domain user to it. Is there any way to do this over a remote VPN connection? As a side note, the VPN does *not* authenticate with domain credentials; it has its own separate login.

I know that on prior versions of windows, you could connect the VPN at the windows login screen, but that no longer seems to be the case with Windows 10 so that doesn't help here.

Comment: Hi, you still can activate a VPN before a login, but it must be made as a service. That avenue is still possible but depend mostly in your vpn client you use if it support it

Comment: @yagmoth555 I have been unable to find a method to do this with windows VPN in windows 10.

Comment: Connect to the VPN while logged in as a local user or with cached credentials for a domain user. Then use the switch user function to log on as a domain user without cached credentials.

Answer (score 2):

With the VPN connected in the session you have. You can shift right click on an exe or shortcut, notepad for example, and run as another user, then the credential will be cache to local, then you can switch to that user.

Answer (score 0):

Answer found a year and a half later. Set up your VPN as accessible to all users, with credentials saved. Then set up a scheduled task at startup, run as SYSTEM, to dial the connection. To be fancy, have the task run a script that checks if the connection is active, and dials again if not, then run the scheduled task every few minutes.